# Why my contact recogniser doesn't work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I made contact recogniser using physics body, category bit mask and SKPhysics contact. Unfortunately it do not work. Could You help me somehow to find mistake? 
This code do not print statement Touched.

Is it because one body is SKSpriteNode and second SKShapeNode? Could we recognise contact between SpriteNode and ShapeNode?

I made all improvements like @giorashc said with SKPhysics body, but in not worked.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

var TouchLevel3BadgeChecker = 0

enum BodyType:UInt32{
    case TheCircle = 1
    case TheEightBack = 2
}


class TouchLevel3SceneClass: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var Eight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "8.png")
    var EightBack = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "8Back.png")


    var counter : Int = 0;

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self



        Eight.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
        Eight.name = "Eight"

        addChild(Eight)


        EightBack.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
        EightBack.name = "EightBack"
        EightBack.zPosition = 2
        EightBack.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(texture: EightBack.texture!,
                                                size: EightBack.texture!.size())
        EightBack.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        EightBack.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        EightBack.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        EightBack.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.TheEightBack.rawValue
        addChild(EightBack)



        Circle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -25)
        Circle.zPosition = 2;
        Circle.fillColor = SKColor.black;
        Circle.name = "Circle"
        Circle.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30)
        Circle.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        Circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        Circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.TheCircle.rawValue
        Circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.TheEightBack.rawValue
        Circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.TheEightBack.rawValue
        addChild(Circle)
   }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches{
            let location = t.location(in: self);


            if atPoint(location).name == "Circle"{
                Circle.position.x = location.x
                Circle.position.y = location.y
            }
        }
    }


        func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.TheCircle.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.TheEightBack.rawValue{
                print("Touched")
            } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.TheCircle.rawValue && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.TheEightBack.rawValue{
                print("Touched")
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the `physicsBody` property. Since its optional and nil setting its properties won't do anything.

create the `physicsBody` property with:

```
EightBack.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(...);
Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(...);
```

check the example in this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody

Comment: I added: 

`EightBack.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: EightBack.texture!,
                                                size: EightBack.texture!.size())
 Circle.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30)`

But still doesn't work